# Throttle Subject in android

Tags: android, rx-java

This is RxJava in **Android**

I have a click listener and inside:

```
oETASubject.onNext(center);
```

The `oETASubject` is `PublishSubject<LatLng>` created with:

```
oETASubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

The observation of this subject is done as follows:

```
oETASubject
            //.throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            //.debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(latLng -> {
                // here is a http call with retrofit that returns an observable
                return returnAnAPIcallObservableHere(latLng);
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(myObserver);
```

### My problem:

If I use `throttleLast` or `debounce` I do not get any results.
Any way I can throttle my requests every 100ms and then get the last value?

Comment: Have you try to add a doOnNext(// log message) call before the flatMap to check if throttleLast and/or debounce emit items ?

(by the way, check rx-android which provide Observable to replace your subject in your ClickListener. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: @dwursteisen thank you. Yes it was indeed emitting results but the thread was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong thread! There I go:

```
.throttleLast(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```